# Combines message for image and information gives "invalid initialization error"

Tags: c++, opencv, ros-kinetic, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am currently trying to implement a message that includes the images as well as the detected bounding boxes.
The publisher works very well, but the subscriber gives me the following error message:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/maybe_include.hpp:18:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function/detail/function_iterate.hpp:14,
                 from /usr/include/boost/preprocessor/iteration/detail/iter/forward1.hpp:52,
                 from /usr/include/boost/function.hpp:64,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/forwards.h:40,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/common.h:37,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/ros/ros.h:43,
                 from /home/marvin/catkin_ws/src/efr_object_detection_camera/src/template_matching.cpp:5:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp: In instantiation of ‘static void boost::detail::function::void_function_invoker1<FunctionPtr, R, T0>::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, T0) [with FunctionPtr = void (*)(const darknet_ros_msgs::ImageWithBoundingBoxes_<std::allocator<void> >&); R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&]’:
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:940:38:   required from ‘void boost::function1<R, T1>::assign_to(Functor) [with Functor = void (*)(const darknet_ros_msgs::ImageWithBoundingBoxes_<std::allocator<void> >&); R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:728:7:   required from ‘boost::function1<R, T1>::function1(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = void (*)(const darknet_ros_msgs::ImageWithBoundingBoxes_<std::allocator<void> >&); R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1077:16:   required from ‘boost::function<R(T0)>::function(Functor, typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type) [with Functor = void (*)(const darknet_ros_msgs::ImageWithBoundingBoxes_<std::allocator<void> >&); R = void; T0 = const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >&; typename boost::enable_if_c<boost::type_traits::ice_not<boost::is_integral<Functor>::value>::value, int>::type = int]’
/home/marvin/catkin_ws/src/efr_object_detection_camera/src/template_matching.cpp:55:26:   required from here
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:118:11: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘const darknet_ros_msgs::ImageWithBoundingBoxes_<std::allocator<void> >&’ from expression of type ‘const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > >’
           BOOST_FUNCTION_RETURN(f(BOOST_FUNCTION_ARGS));
           ^
```

This is the message in question:

> Header header

> Header image_header

> BoundingBox[] bounding_boxes

> sensor_msgs/Image im

And this is my subscriber:

```
void imageCallback(const darknet_ros_msgs::ImageWithBoundingBoxes& msg) {
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
    try {
        cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(msg.im, sensor_msgs::image_encodings::BGR8);
        Mat image = cv_ptr->image;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < msg.bounding_boxes.size(); i++)
        {
            darknet_ros_msgs::BoundingBox bBox= msg.bounding_boxes[i];
            double minx = bBox.xmin;
            double miny = bBox.ymin;
            double maxx = bBox.xmax;
            double maxy = bBox.ymax;
            match(image);
        }
        
        cv::waitKey(30);
    } catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e) {
        ROS_ERROR("Could not convert from '%s' to 'bgr8'.",
        msg.im.encoding.c_str());
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ros::init(argc, argv, "template_matching_node");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    cv::namedWindow("view");
    cv::startWindowThread();
    image_transport::ImageTransport it(nh);
    image_transport::Subscriber sub = it.subscribe("/darknet_ros/ImageWithBoundingBoxes", 1,
            imageCallback);
    ros::spin();
    cv::destroyWindow("view");
    ros::shutdown();
    return 0;
}
```

Could anybody help me to fix that error?
Thanks!

I am using kinetic kame with Ubuntu 16.04 and as you can see everything is programmed in C++.
For any further information please ask!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322153/combines-message-for-image-and-information-gives-%22invalid-initialization-error%22/) by [MarviB16](https://answers.ros.org/users/41101/marvib16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Isn't the problem here that you're trying to use `image_transport::Subscriber` to subscribe to a topic which isn't actually carrying `Image`s, but `darknet_ros_msgs::ImageWithBoundingBoxes`?

That's also what the error message seems to tell you. Paraphrasing, it would read:

> ```
> error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘darknet_ros_msgs::ImageWithBoundingBoxes&’ from expression of type ‘boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Image>
> ```

You'll probably have to switch to a regular `ros::Subscriber` instead of using `image_transport`'s.

---

Edit:

> Oh, right yes... But how could I rewrite it? So that I still can use the image_transport functionality?

I'm not sure. Possibly *not* using a custom message, but using something like [message_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) to combine related messages based on their timestamps (so only publish a list of boundingboxes (one from [vision_msgs](http://wiki.ros.org/vision_msgs) preferably) with the same timestamp as the `sensor_msgs/Image` that the detection was run on, then later recombine the two using `message_filters`).

I'm not an `image_transport` expert though, so there could be a different option.

There is a tutorial on writing your own transport plugin ([this one](http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/WritingNewTransport)), but I don't believe that is something that would fit your use-case.

---

Edit 2:

> Edit: Thank you! Now it works. But what I am still not sure about: Is it now slower? Because i don't use the image transport functionality?

Using `image_transport` doesn't make anything magically faster. The "only" thing `image_transport` does is making it easier to use different compression algorithms (called "transports" in `image_transport` lingo) without having to deal with their details in image producers and consumers. Simply configure a specific transport to be used, and without recompiling or changing anything in your publishers or subscribers it will be used. Transparently.

In the case of compression, this actually has the potential to make things *slower* (as compression adds overhead), but that obviously depends on a number of other factors (size of images vs bandwidth, latency, etc).

So with switching to a regular `Subscriber`, you lose all of that. But you had already lost that, as you were using a regular `Publisher` as well.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MarviB16](https://answers.ros.org/users/41101/marvib16/) on 2019-04-29**:
Oh, right yes...
But how could I rewrite it?
So that I still can use the image_transport functionality?

Edit: Thank you! Now it works. But what I am still not sure about: Is it now slower? Because i don't use the image transport functionality?